# AMP page not loading custom JS script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, amp-html

I want to migrate HTML5 page to AMP. How to load CSS, external jQuery and existing custom JS file to google AMP page.

```html
//Below is the Index.html file content
<amp-script layout="container" src="dist\topics\smart.js">
    <p>Initial content that can be modified from JavaScript</p>
</amp-script>

/*Below is the content of the js file*/

function hello(){
    
    this.alert("hello world");
}

/*At the time of js function calling in the index file, then Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined, error is coming.*/
```

Comment: not seeing any jQuery here. Try starting with similar amp-script examples, and then show what breaks. also, if you are trying to use jQuery, it won't work because of size limitations. your javascript needs to be sans-library (without external libs)

Comment: you will need to use one of those methods here

https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/